# MS Access Query Performance Issue

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

The following query works, sometimes.

The usual problem when I run the query it does not show the record count of those records over 180 old although it does show all other data.

l_section & dim_performance_score are SharePoint 2010 lists.

I want a report that shows the records that are less than 90 days old, >=90 and < 180 days old, and >=180 days old.

If I make five different stored queries and left join them, the query works consistently. However, when I consolidate all the SQL into one stored query, things get flakey. Not withstanding the performance issue, if I try to look at the consolidate query in the design window, MS Access crashes.  Is this a known issue with JET?

It seems inefficient to have to maintain 5 or 6 different queries to get one answer.

Is what I am doing the best way to go about getting the desired data?

```
PARAMETERS [compare date] DateTime;

SELECT
    l_section.section, 
    [compare date] AS [As of Date],
    total_count.[Total Records],
    IIf([less_than_90].[<90 Days] Is Null,0,[less_than_90].[<90 Days]) AS [<90 Days],
    IIf([greater_than_90].[>=90 & <180Days] Is Null,0,[greater_than_90].[>=90 & <180Days]) AS [>=90 & <180Days],
    IIf([greater_than_180].[>=180 Days] Is Null,0,[greater_than_180].[>=180 Days]) AS [>=180 Days]

FROM 
    (
        (
            (
                l_section 
                LEFT JOIN
                    (
                        SELECT
                            since_modified.section,
                            Count(since_modified.section) AS [>=180 Days]
                        FROM 
                            (
                                SELECT 
                                    l_section.section, 
                                    IIf(dim_performance_score.[Modified] Is Null,0,DateDiff("d",dim_performance_score.[Modified],[compare date])) AS days_since_update
                                FROM
                                    l_section
                                LEFT JOIN
                                    dim_performance_score
                                ON
                                    l_section.section = dim_performance_score.section
                            ) as since_modified
                        WHERE 
                            (((since_modified.days_since_update)>=180))
                        GROUP BY 
                            since_modified.section
                    ) as greater_than_180 
                ON
                    l_section.section = greater_than_180.section
            )
            LEFT JOIN
                (
                    SELECT 
                        since_modified.section,
                        Count(since_modified.section) AS [<90 Days]
                    FROM
                        (
                            SELECT 
                                l_section.section, 
                                IIf(dim_performance_score.[Modified] Is Null,0,DateDiff("d",dim_performance_score.[Modified],[compare date])) AS days_since_update
                            FROM
                                l_section
                            LEFT JOIN
                                dim_performance_score
                            ON
                                l_section.section = dim_performance_score.section
                        ) as since_modified
                    WHERE 
                        (((since_modified.days_since_update)<90))
                    GROUP BY
                        since_modified.section
                ) as less_than_90
            ON 
                l_section.section = less_than_90.section
        )
        LEFT JOIN
            (
                SELECT
                    since_modified.section,
                    Count(since_modified.section) AS [>=90 & <180Days]
                FROM 
                    (
                        SELECT 
                            l_section.section, 
                            IIf(dim_performance_score.[Modified] Is Null,0,DateDiff("d",dim_performance_score.[Modified],[compare date])) AS days_since_update
                        FROM
                            l_section
                        LEFT JOIN
                            dim_performance_score
                        ON
                            l_section.section = dim_performance_score.section
                    ) as since_modified                 
                WHERE 
                    (((since_modified.days_since_update)>=90 
                    And
                    (since_modified.days_since_update)<180))
                GROUP BY 
                    since_modified.section
            ) as greater_than_90 
        ON
            l_section.section = greater_than_90.section
    )
    LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT
                l_section.section,
                Count(IIf([section] Is Null,0,[section])) AS [Total Records]
            FROM
                l_section
            LEFT JOIN
                dim_performance_score
            ON
                l_section.section = dim_performance_score.section
            GROUP BY l_section.section
        ) as total_count 
    ON
        l_section.section = total_count.section
ORDER BY l_section.section;
```

Answer (score 0):

A triple-nested join?  That can't be right.  It looks like each join is (or should be) on the same level.

```
PARAMETERS [compare date] DateTime;

SELECT
    l_section.section, 
    [compare date] AS [As of Date],
    total_count.[Total Records],
    IIf([less_than_90].[<90 Days] Is Null,0,[less_than_90].[<90 Days]) AS [<90 Days],
    IIf([greater_than_90].[>=90 & <180Days] Is Null,0,[greater_than_90].[>=90 & <180Days]) AS [>=90 & <180Days],
    IIf([greater_than_180].[>=180 Days] Is Null,0,[greater_than_180].[>=180 Days]) AS [>=180 Days]

FROM l_section 
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            since_modified.section,
            Count(since_modified.section) AS [>=180 Days]
        FROM 
            (
                SELECT 
                    l_section.section, 
                    IIf(dim_performance_score.[Modified] Is Null,0,DateDiff("d",dim_performance_score.[Modified],[compare date])) AS days_since_update
                FROM
                    l_section
                LEFT JOIN
                    dim_performance_score
                ON
                    l_section.section = dim_performance_score.section
            ) as since_modified
        WHERE 
            (((since_modified.days_since_update)>=180))
        GROUP BY 
            since_modified.section
    ) as greater_than_180 
ON
    l_section.section = greater_than_180.section

LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            since_modified.section,
            Count(since_modified.section) AS [<90 Days]
        FROM
            (
                SELECT 
                    l_section.section, 
                    IIf(dim_performance_score.[Modified] Is Null,0,DateDiff("d",dim_performance_score.[Modified],[compare date])) AS days_since_update
                FROM
                    l_section
                LEFT JOIN
                    dim_performance_score
                ON
                    l_section.section = dim_performance_score.section
            ) as since_modified
        WHERE 
            (((since_modified.days_since_update)<90))
        GROUP BY
            since_modified.section
    ) as less_than_90
ON 
    l_section.section = less_than_90.section

LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            since_modified.section,
            Count(since_modified.section) AS [>=90 & <180Days]
        FROM 
            (
                SELECT 
                    l_section.section, 
                    IIf(dim_performance_score.[Modified] Is Null,0,DateDiff("d",dim_performance_score.[Modified],[compare date])) AS days_since_update
                FROM
                    l_section
                LEFT JOIN
                    dim_performance_score
                ON
                    l_section.section = dim_performance_score.section
            ) as since_modified                 
        WHERE 
            (((since_modified.days_since_update)>=90 
            And
            (since_modified.days_since_update)<180))
        GROUP BY 
            since_modified.section
    ) as greater_than_90 
ON
    l_section.section = greater_than_90.section

LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            l_section.section,
            Count(IIf([section] Is Null,0,[section])) AS [Total Records]
        FROM
            l_section
        LEFT JOIN
            dim_performance_score
        ON
            l_section.section = dim_performance_score.section
        GROUP BY l_section.section
    ) as total_count 
ON
    l_section.section = total_count.section

ORDER BY l_section.section;
```

Comment: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression l_section.section = greater_than_180.section LEFT JOIN     (
        SELECT 
            since_modified.section,
            Count(since_modified.section) AS [<90 Days]
        FROM
            ('

Comment: I think each join is on the same level in that there needs to be a record for each section in l_section and nulls converted to zero.

Comment: Try adding one section at a time and commenting out the rest.  I can't see the data so I can only guess, but structurally what I wrote is sound.  So try it with just the first "LEFT JOIN" section and see what happens.  If that works, add the next LEFT JOIN and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out a different way of getting what I wanted and it is much simpler. I am posting as my own answer to show the before and after.

```
SELECT

        section_last_modified.section,
        Count(section_last_modified.section) AS [Total Records],
        Sum(IIf([days_since_modified]<90,1,0)) AS [< 90 days],
        Sum(IIf([days_since_modified] Between 90 And 180,1,0)) AS [>=90 and <180 days],
        Sum(IIf([days_since_modified]>=180,1,0)) AS [>=180 days]

FROM section_last_modified

GROUP BY section_last_modified.section;



-----section_last_modified-------

PARAMETERS [Compare Date] DateTime;
SELECT
        dim_performance_score.section,
        DateDiff("d",dim_performance_score.[Modified],[Compare Date]) AS days_since_modified
FROM
        dim_performance_score
WHERE
        (((dim_performance_score.[Content Type])="stacker maintenance"))
ORDER BY
        dim_performance_score.section;
```